# running windows universal app on emulator in vs2015 on win7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, emulation, windows-7-x64, windows-10-universal

I have been using the following tutorial 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-basic-windows-10-app-in-cpp
in order to create some simple windows universal app. I have vs2015 professional with all ad-dons installed needed for the windows universal app development. I have win7 x64 sp1, and I wanted to test the app using some emulator/simulator, however I cant configure it on vs2015 as shown in the link. Are win10 necessary for testing or 
is there any way to run windows universal app in some emulator/simulator in vs2015 on a win7 64-bit machine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8.1: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can use the emulators in Visual Studio, but not the simulator.

Windows 7: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can’t use the emulators or the simulator in Visual Studio either. Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx).

It would be advisable to use W10. UWP takes advantage of One Core common across all Win10 devices.

Comment: Thx for the response. I am not in a position to upgrade my windows to win10, is there a way to use VM with win 10 as use simulator/emulator there? Or deploy the app there?
thx

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. You only can build UWP apps on Windows 10. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx) for more info (Requirement section)